# Android bluetooth send int array

Tags: java, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

I need to send an int array in android through Bluetooth it was allowing to send as one by one int  only. So is there any way to send complete int array at a time.

There is a possibility to send byte array but I dont want to convert to byte . As my data contains some int value when converting that into a byte it taking as signed byte I want it to be unsigned byte. There is no possibility for the unsigned byte in java so I want to sent as int only.

Comment: Are you sure you know what you are doing? When you want to send an `int` you will *of course* not convert that `int` to a single `byte`. You will [send four bytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putInt(int))

Answer (score 0):

I'm 'sending' data to my Android application over a Bluetooth connection (using Visual Studio).  The Bluetooth write and read functions take a byte[] array, which is a value from -128 to +127.  My A/D converter program needs to send values 0 to 256 to Android.  So what I did is take the received value (example 130 becomes a byte value -126.  On the Android receive buffer my codes checks for a negative value. If < 0 then number=256+received value.  Simple. I hope this helps

Here is a simple "test" routine:

```
// Short, Int Test
    byte current = (byte) 130;
    int intCurrent = 0;

    if (current < 0){
        // Negative value
        intCurrent = 256 + current;
    }
    else
    {
        intCurrent = (int) current;
    }
```